# Hardtime trying to make a table with colored lines and elements between

Tags: javascript, html, css

This what I have a doubt and what i have to do
[image: This what I have a doubt and what i have to do]

This what I have done so far
[image: This what I have done so far]

Im having a hard time cracking this, my doubt is how can i make this space between the elements also this border colored in Gray and Red and this vertical line between the two of them, i can only make this with pure HTML,CSS and JS without any framework/lib/api.

I tried something like this, but still doesn't work the way i want, if anyone can help i will be grateful

```css
    .table {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 0rem;   
    margin-left: 5rem;    
     
}

.fgraphs {

    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .fgraphs:before,
  .fgraphs:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .fgraphs:before {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #979797;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .fgraphs:after {
    border-bottom: 3.5px solid #F03D24;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  }
```

```html
    <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Domingo</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Segunda</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Terça</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quarta</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinta</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sexta</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sábado</td>
                    <td>Icone</td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td><img src="./images/cloudy-day-3.svg" alt=""></td>
                    <td>20ºC</td>
                    <td class="fgraphs"></td>
                    <td>32ºC</td>
                </tr>                 
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your html is completely invalid

Comment: As mentioned, your table layout is off. Here is something that will help you out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Thanks, i will check !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen you been struggling with this layout for a few days. Thought I would be helpful and show you the basic idea with flexbox and using before and after elements.

```css
header,
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1.2rem 0;
}

.barLeft {
  position:relative;
  border-right: 3px dashed #CCC;
  text-align: right;
}

.barRight {
  position:relative;
}

.barLeft::before, .barRight::before {
  position:absolute;
  content: '';
  top:50%;
  margin-top: -1px; /* half of the border */
  border-top: 2px dotted #CCC;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.barRight span{
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -1.5px; /* half the vert border */
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.barLeft span{
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -1.5px; /* half the vert border */
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  margin-right: -1.5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">FOOO</div>
    <div class="col">BAR</div>
    <div class="col">GOO</div>
    <div class="col">World</div>
    <div class="col barLeft"><span style="width:10%"></span></div>
    <div class="col barRight"><span style="width:50%"></span></div>
    <div class="col">100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col barLeft"><span style="width:20%"></span></div>
    <div class="col barRight"><span style="width:30%"></span></div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
  </div>  
</section>
```